# insert a database value to a string array - not working

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, database

Cheers,

Im trying to insert a database value to my string array.

for some reason, it says :

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

This is my code :

```
if (IsPostBack)
{
    if (RadioWords.Checked == true)
    {
        con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=MICROSOF-58B8A5\\SQL_SERVER_R2;Initial Catalog=Daniel;Integrated Security=True");
        con.Open();

        string SqlCount = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM WordGame";

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(SqlCount, con);

        //Sets an array of the size of the database.
        int count = (Int32)command.ExecuteScalar();
        arrOfWords = new string[count];

        //Initialize the words in the array.
        for (int i = 0; i < arrOfWords.Length; i++)
        {
            int GetRandomNumber =  rnd.Next(1, arrOfWords.Length);

            string Sqlinsert = "SELECT Word FROM WordGame WHERE ID='"+GetRandomNumber+"'";

            SqlCommand commandToRandom = new SqlCommand(Sqlinsert, con);

            arrOfWords[i] = commandToRandom.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
        }
    }
```

and its refering to this line :

```
int GetRandomNumber =  rnd.Next(1, arrOfWords.Length);
```

Thanks for the helpers!

Comment: You should absolutely properly dispose the connection and command objects (and if you plan on using one, the reader too). In a small-scale test this will seem to work, but you're going to run out of resources (connections) very quickly on a server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

rnd is null , add a line

`rnd = new Random();`

at the start of your event

Answer (score 1):

```java
rnd = new Random();
```

Instantiate `rnd` as above. You're using a `null` object that causes the exception in your question to be thrown.